# Welche Bedeutung hat der Duden im praktischen Gebrauch?

Tags: reformed-orthography

Dass der Duden das Referenzwerk für die Orthografie der deutschen Sprache ist, ist unbestritten.

Für einen Teil der Verwender der deutschen Sprache ist die Befolgung dieser Regeln bindend.

Etwa Schulen, Kinder, indirekt deren Eltern, Behörden, Zeitungen, Verlagswesen und natürlich Fremdsprachler, die ihre Deutschkenntnisse zertifizieren müssen.

Deutsche, die ihre sprachliche Erziehung lange vor der Rechtschreibreform abgeschlossen haben, werden ihn eher ignorieren. Ein bisschen als Kuriosum und vielleicht irgendwo im Schrank stehend.

Für diese Gruppe ist praktisch die Rechtschreibkorrektur (Spellchecker) von Microsoft Word und Co. entscheidender.

Irgendwie stören ja diese roten Schlangenlinien und auf diese Weise assimilieren ältere Sprecher Teile der Rechtschreibreform.

Der Duden selbst ist dieser Gruppe ziemlich egal.

Ich selbst besitze auch keinen gedruckten neuen Duden.

**Edit:**

Ich behaupte mal, wer berufsmäßig einen großen Teil seiner formellen Schreiben am Computer verfasst und nicht zu strikter Befolgung der aktuellen Rechtschreibregeln verpflichtet ist, wird den Duden als Buch nicht gebrauchen und schon gar nicht als kostenpflichtige Onlinedienste.

Eventuell hat er eine Duden-Rechtschreibkorrektur installiert.

Praktisch wird er einfach die verwenden, die auf seinem Computer installiert ist.

Comment: Verlagswesen? Benutzt die FAZ nicht noch die alte Rechtschreibung?

Comment: *"Der Duden als Referenzwerk für die Orthografie der deutschen Sprache ist unbestritten."* ich stimme der Aussage nicht zu. Der Duden ist weder ein offizielles Referenzwerk und als inofizielles auch umstritten. Wenn schon, müsste man mit  http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/regelwerk.html vergleichen.

Comment: Inwiefern ist er Duden umstritten?

Comment: Als praktisches Hilfsmittel um nachzuweisen, dass eine Formulierung den aktuellen Forderungen entspricht. Duden wird übrigens nicht nur Markenname verstanden, sondern tendenziell als Gattungsbegriff.

Comment: @swegi ich meinte, es ist umstritten, dass der Duden *die Autorität* sei. Die Duden-online-Rechtschreibprüfung scheidet übrigens im Test ziemlich schlecht ab: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/duden-online-rechtschreibkorrektur.php

Comment: @splattne -- Danke für diesen Link!

Comment: Das liest sich eher wie ein Essay. Kann man sicherlich drastisch kürzen. Und bitte *abschließend* auch wirklich eine *Frage* stellen – und zwar nach Möglichkeit eine, auf die es eine objektiv korrekte, nachprüfbare Antwort gibt. | I am closing this in its current form as per the [„Good Subjective, Bad Subjective“](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) blog post.

Answer (score 3):

Der Duden ist zwar sehr verbreitet und wird in sprachlichen Zweifelsfällen häufig als Autorität zitiert, hat aber offiziell keine keine Sonderstellung unter den verschiedenen Werken, die existieren.

Die Wörter- und Rechtschreibbücher von Duden sind nur eine Interpretation des [amtlichen Regelwerks](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/rechtschreibung/regelwerk.html) eines Verlags (von vielen).

Comment: Ich fasse Duden nicht nur als Markenname auf, sondern als Gattungsbegriff, der sich auf alle diese Interpretationen bezieht. Das amtliche Regelwerk ist für einen nicht Sprachwissenschaftler schlicht unverdaulich.

Comment: Hör mir auf mit der Behördengläubigkeit. Was du *amtlich* nennst, heißt nicht, dass das ein Gesetz sei, das du zu befolgen hättest oder dass diese Regeln in irgend einer Weise ehrwürdig seien. Es heißt nur, dass im Schriftverkehr dieser Behörden diese Regeln anzuwenden sind und dass dagegen verstoßende Bedienstete prinzipiell mit Abmahnungen o.ä. malträtiert werden können. Du als freier Bürger, ich als freier Verleger - wir können schreiben, wie wir wollen. (Unfrei sind allerdings die Schüler, die in vom Staat beaufsichtigten Schulen schreiben und dafür gute Noten bekommen wollen.)

Comment: @Christial Geiselmann Finde deinen Kommentar unnötig überzogen.

Answer (score 1):

Ich gehe stark davon aus, dass die Regeln des Dudens sich in der Rechtschreibkorrektur widerspiegeln. So gesehen benutzt man den Duden, auch wenn man keine gedruckte Ausgabe hat.
Ich glaube auch nicht, dass Deutsche, die ihre sprachliche Erziehung vor dem Beginn der Rechtschreibreform hatten, auf den Duden verzichten. Gerade diese nehmen vielleicht eher die gedruckte Ausgabe zu Hilfe als die Online-Ausgabe. Meine Mutter kauft sich zumindest regelmäßig den neuen Duden.

Comment: Ich bediene mich des Duden (und zwar vorzugsweise des alten, vor-RSR-lichen, in der Ausgabe von 1989) arbeitstäglich. Er liegt dazu stets griffbereit auf meinem Schreibtisch. - Zum Spaß vergleiche ich ab und zu, was hier drin steht und was in der neuesten Ausgabe steht (die ich in Elektronenform nutze).